# How To import excel (.xlsx) Zend3 framework

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I have tried integrate phpExcel library into zend 3 framework.
for this I have added phpexcel library into vendor folder and modified the
following files to install library without composer

1.modules.config.php in config folder Just add the module name in the return array. 2. autoload_psr4.php in vendor/composer directory Add your module information to return array in following format 'Modulename' => array($modulepath), 3. autoload_static.php in vendor/composer directory Here we have to add the module information in two places 1. In $prefixLengthsPsr4 array as 'M' => array( 'Modulename' => 11, ), The key value indicates the first letter of module name and the numerical value is the length of modulename +1(for /). 2. In $prefixDirsPsr4 array as 'modulename' => array ( 0 => DIR . '/../..' . '/module/modulename/src', ),

But getting error as

**Uncaught Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException: Module (Phpexcel) could not be initialized. in /usersdev/god/god2sd12472.dev/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php:203 Stack trace: #0**

Can any one help me into this

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I use the phpspreadsheet module which is installed directly by `composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet` and which offers all satisfaction. See at https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.